# Not able to save data in teacher table in entity frame work core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have define this one to many relation in academy and teacher table

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Teacher>().HasKey(x => x.Id);
modelBuilder.Entity<Teacher>().Property(x => x.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
modelBuilder.Entity<Teacher>().Property(x => x.FirstName).HasMaxLength(100).IsRequired();
modelBuilder.Entity<Teacher>().Property(x => x.LastName).HasMaxLength(100).IsRequired();
modelBuilder.Entity<Teacher>().HasOne(a => a.Academy).WithMany(t => t.Teachers).HasForeignKey(a => a.AcademyId);
```

when try to save data in teacher table giving error of null entry in academy table but i try to save in teacher table please help to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The teacher is a member of an academy, therefore you cannot save a teacher without specifying his/her academy, see

```
HasForeignKey(a => a.AcademyId);
```

and read the docs for [HasForeignKey](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/hasforeignkey-method). This specifies that `AcademyId` is a `foreign key`.